# How can I refer to localhost\SQLEXPRESS in an SSMS query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to construct a 4-part name that refers to the `SQLEXPRESS` instance on my local machine, without needing to use the computer name?

I can construct a connection string with

```
server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```

and it works. I can tell SSMS to "Connect to..." `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and it works.

But it seems that if I want to write a query that explicitly refers to the local instance, I need to write:

```
select * from [MY_COMPUTER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS].DataBase.Schema.Table
```

Comment: Are you running this query from a remote server though?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an alias for your localhost, please follow the below mentioned steps to create an alias.

Open Sql Server Configuration Manager.

GoTo: SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration, Aliases(right click and select New Alias).

Create a new Alias with the following settings:

Alias Name: 
Pipe Name: \MyComputerName\pipe\MSSQL$sql2008\sql\query
Protocol: Named Pipes
Server: MyComputerName

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create link server. You will get this option under server name -> Sever Objects - > Linked Server. Here you can create new linked server.

Comment: You mean link server to connect to the localhost?